# WordPress XML RPC Upload Image C#

Tags: c#, image, wordpress, file-upload

Hey all, I am developing a site for work that will push info from a database into Wordpress using Wordpress XML RPC.  I can grab info and post it just fine, however when I get to the point of uploading images it seems to work(no runtime errors/image in WP Media Tab) however it uploads a broken image link. It appears it is somehow no getting the data from my image and I am not certain why here is some of my code.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("_Images/DownloadButton-PSD.png"));
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    byte[] imagebytes = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.Read(imagebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length));
```

after that code loads the image info I pass it to the function in the format of a Data variable

```
var data = new Data
    {
     Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imagebytes),
     Name = "DownloadButton-PSD.png",
     Type = "image/png",
     Overwrite = false,
    };
    _wpWrapper.UploadFile(data);
```

FYI: I am also using the dll's from
http://joeblogs.codeplex.com/
for my project

The Data Class looks like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Base64 { get; set; }
    public bool Overwrite { get; set; }
}
```

The Upload File Function looks like this:

```
public void UploadFile(Data data)
    {
        var xmlRpcData = Map.From.Data(data);
        var result = _wrapper.UploadFile(this.BlogID, Username, Password, xmlRpcData);

    }
```

Comment: Essentially no, at the time I was doing this the JoeBlogs codebase was incomplete.  From what I have seen though you want to use MediaObjects rather than Files.

Comment: See solution here. It might be for an older version, but you should be able to use it, [http://pixpuffindev.blogspot.com/2012/08/posting-to-wordpress-with-c-using.html](http://pixpuffindev.blogspot.com/2012/08/posting-to-wordpress-with-c-using.html)

Answer (score 2):

In JoeBlogs library try using the class `MetaWeblogWrapper` and method: `MediaObjectInfo NewMediaObject(MediaObject mediaObject)` - for upload image.